# Click and wait for the new page to load

Tags: javascript, dom, phantomjs, casperjs

I am trying to login to a webpage. I filled the username and the password and also clicked the login button as shown in the code below.

```
casper.start(startURL, function () {
        this.fill('.header-login-wrap', { // FILL THE USERNAME AND PASSWORD
            email: username,
            password: password
        }, false); // Do not submit the form immediately

        this.click('.btn-login'); // CLICK THE LOGIN BUTTON

        this.waitForSelector('.modal',
            function pass() {
                console.log('pass');
            },
            function fail(resp) {
                console.log('fail', resp);
            }
        );
    });
```

After I have clicked the button, how to get to the new page. As soon as we log in, we are presented with a `modal` that has a class `.modal`. I am trying to wait before it loads. But every time the function `fail` is called with `resp = 5000`. Do not understand what it means. Is this the correct way to click the login button and then wait for the new page to load?

Comment: Seems to me, that it has exceeded timeout, have you tried to setting it more than 5 seconds?

Comment: @holmicz Tried increasing to 20 seconds. Now getting `fail 20000
[info] [phantom] Done 3 steps in 30241ms
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=about:blank, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=true
[debug] [phantom] url changed to "about:blank"`

Comment: It's possible that your target page isn't even loaded — maybe they ban bots. You need to have some form of damage control in the script to cover such situations: log errors, make screenshots.

Comment: @Vaviloff Is the method of filling username and password, clicking the login button and then waiting for the selector correct? What  should I do to take screenshots, log errors?

Comment: @Vaviloff I took the screenshot and I can see the login page where the username and password details have been filled out but nothing more.

Comment: So, basically, navigation to the new page is not happening. You should try to figure out why. Sorry for not being able to help more — I find CasperJS script language confusing, unintuitive and use native PhantomJS for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

First, have you tried set to `true` the last parameter of `fill()`?

```
this.fill('.header-login-wrap', { // FILL THE USERNAME AND PASSWORD
        email: username,
        password: password
    }, true); // Submit the form immediately
```

If this doesn't work, try to separating in steps, like `casper.then()` steps:

```
casper.start(startURL, function () {
        this.fill('.header-login-wrap', { // FILL THE USERNAME AND PASSWORD
            email: username,
            password: password
        }, false); // Do not submit the form immediately
});
casper.then(function(){
    this.click('.btn-login'); // CLICK THE LOGIN BUTTON
});

casper.then(function(){
    this.waitForSelector('.modal', function(){
                this.capture('after_login.png');
                this.echo('pass');
            },function() {
                this.capture('after_login_fail.png');
                this.echo('fail');
            }
        );
});
```

All this assuming the selectors are the correct ones. I added `capture()` to log on images what the script is 'seeing'. For this you have to set the `loadImages`: to `true`on `pageSettings` when creating the casper object.